# Dynamic ListView Item Not Populating XML

Tags: android, listview, firebase

I have a dynamic ListView that I am updating based on a Firebase listener. I initially populate the ListView, and then as items are added to Firebase I call notifySetDataChanged() to update the ListView.

Code:

```
public class Discussion_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView mPollImage;
private TextView mPollCommentQuestion;

private EditText mUserComment;
private String mUserID;
private ImageView mUserAvatar;
private ListView mPollCommentsList;
private ArrayAdapter<Comments> mCommentAdapter;
private int mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll;
private ArrayList<Comments> mCommentArrayList;
private ArrayList<String> mCommentIDArrayList;

private Firebase mBaseRef;
private Firebase mPollsRef;
private Firebase mUpdateRef;
private Firebase mCommentsRef;

private DateFormat mDateFormat;
private Date mDate;
private String mCurrentDateString;

private int mPollIndex;

private ChildEventListener mUpdateComments;

private Toolbar toolbar;


private static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://fan-polls.firebaseio.com/";
private static final String COMMENTS_LABEL = "Comments";
private static final String POLLS_LABEL = "Polls";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_discussion);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle(R.string.discussion_title_text);

    mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    mDate = new Date();
    mCurrentDateString = mDateFormat.format(mDate);

    mBaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    mPollsRef = mBaseRef.child(POLLS_LABEL);

    mPollImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.comments_image);
    mPollCommentQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poll_comment_question);

    mUserComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_comment);
    mUserAvatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image_avatar);
    mPollCommentsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poll_comments_list);
    mCommentArrayList = new ArrayList<Comments>();
    mCommentIDArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mCommentAdapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.individual_comment, mCommentArrayList);
    mPollCommentsList.setAdapter(mCommentAdapter);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String pollID = intent.getStringExtra("POLL_ID");
    mPollIndex = intent.getIntExtra("POLL_INDEX", 0);
    mUpdateRef = mPollsRef.child(mCurrentDateString).child(String.valueOf(mPollIndex + 1));
    mCommentsRef = mUpdateRef.child(COMMENTS_LABEL);


    mUpdateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            setImage(dataSnapshot);
            setQuestion(dataSnapshot);
            createInitialCommentArray(dataSnapshot);
            mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll = (int) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).getChildrenCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll; i++){
                String commentID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(mCommentIDArrayList.get(i)).child("COMMENT").getValue();
                Log.v("COMMENT_ID", "The comment ID is " + commentID);
                String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(mCommentIDArrayList.get(i)).child("USER_ID").getValue();
                Log.v("USER_ID", "The user ID is " + userID);
                mCommentArrayList.add(new Comments(mUserAvatar, userID, commentID));
                mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    //TODO: Store unique comment ID's in an array

    //TODO: Figure out how to programmatically add images to AWS and then store URL in Firebase
    ImageView fab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_comment);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            HashMap<String, Object> commentMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            commentMap.put("USER_ID", mBaseRef.getAuth().getUid());
            commentMap.put("COMMENT", mUserComment.getText().toString());
            mUpdateRef.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).push().updateChildren(commentMap);
            mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            hideKeyboard(view);
            mUserComment.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.comment_added, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}


//How to iterate through a Firbease database
private void createInitialCommentArray(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).getChildren()) {
        mCommentIDArrayList.add(s.getKey());
        Log.v("COMMENT_ARRAY", "The comment array is " + s.getKey());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mUpdateComments = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            mCommentIDArrayList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            String commentID = (String) dataSnapshot.child("COMMENT").getValue();
            Log.v("New_Comment", "The new comment is " + commentID);
            String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child("USER_ID").getValue();
            Log.v("New_User_ID", "The new userID is " + userID);
            mCommentArrayList.add(new Comments(mUserAvatar, userID, commentID));
            mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    };

    //TODO: Keep listeners lean; only add listener to the specific root of the data
    mCommentsRef.addChildEventListener(mUpdateComments);

    }

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mCommentsRef.removeEventListener(mUpdateComments);
}

private void setQuestion(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String pollQuestion = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Poll_Question").getValue();
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
        mPollCommentQuestion.setTextSize(24);
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
        mPollCommentQuestion.setTextSize(18);
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
        mPollCommentQuestion.setTextSize(14);
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
        mPollCommentQuestion.setTextSize(14);
    }
    mPollCommentQuestion.setText(pollQuestion);
}

public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Adapter -

```
    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Comments> {

        public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Comments> items) {
            super(context, resource, items);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.individual_comment, null);
            }

            Comments p = getItem(position);

            if (p != null) {
                TextView userID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_ID);
                TextView userComment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_comment);

                if (userID != null) {
                    userID.setText(p.getUserID());
                }

                if (userComment != null) {
                    userComment.setText(p.getUserComment());
                }
            }


            return v;
        }

    }

    private void setImage(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String imageURL = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue();
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(imageURL)
                .transform(new RoundedTransformation(10, 6))
                .fit()
                .into((mPollImage));
        mPollImage.setColorFilter(Color.argb(140, 255, 255, 255)); // White Tint
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` which will be invoked only once and will get unregistered after got invoked. So when the data gets changed in the firebase database in case you change it (as you are doing it in `fab` onclick), you'll not get the callback for data changed as your listener is no longer registered.

For your task, you either need to use `addValueEventListener()` or implement Child event listeners.
And yes, don't forget to remove those when you no longer need it.
Your `onChildAdded()` has issues.

```
String commentID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(pollCount).child("COMMENT").getValue();
String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(pollCount).child("USER_ID").getValue();
```

Above statements will not behave as you expect them to do so.
As per your fab `fab.setOnClickListener()`, you are generating random unique keys as a child of COMMENTS_LABEL and that key contains your user_id and comment.

But you are trying to fetch the user_id and comment from the child of COMMENTS_LABEL using  index 0,1,2,etc. which will never fetch the exact values you saved as you don't know what is the unique id.
You need to change `onChildAdded()` somewhat like this-

```
@Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String commentID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("COMMENT").getValue();
            String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("USER_ID").getValue();
            mCommentArrayList.add(new Comments(mUserAvatar, userID, commentID));
            mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: I have actually adde the code snippet where I include the ChildEventListener. However, nothing is being added to the ListView when I click the add button. Please see edit in my original code.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: It still isn't working, the adapter doesn't appear to be recognizing the onChildAdded() Listener. I have updated my code per your instruction.

Comment: Might be the code flow issue . So please tell me where you added ChildEventListener and is your data getting reflected in the firebase console after you add a new one ? Also is ChildAdded being invoked ?

Comment: Seems you edited your code now. My solution was as per your last edit. Where is `mCommentsRef` instantiated and which node does it points to ?

Comment: The data is correctly being added and read from Firebase, as I have logged those items. However, the ListView simply is not updating. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Let me make myself clear. Now you are getting the child listeners callback when you add a new item . It's just that your list is not updated, right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112636/discussion-between-tccpg288-and-shadab-ansari).

Comment: The culprit is your  `@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll; -- This is the culprit
        }`
You are returning the initial number of items. So the new items added will not be shown. You have to change that by returning the number of updated items.

Comment: Remove `getCount()` method and it will automatically be taken care of.